# How to compare max value in each group to current row? - SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, window-functions

I want to apply conditional logic based on whether or not my `item_no` is the highest in its group.

Sample Data:

```
group_id    item_no
oiegown     1
oiegown     2
oiegown     3
wefwefw     1
wefwefw     2
```

My Approach:

```
CASE WHEN (
  SELECT MAX(item_no)
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY group_id
) = item_no
  THEN /*logic here*/
```

My subquery, as desired, retrieves the highest `item_no` per group.

However, the query does not work as I get the `Scalar subquery produced more than one element` error. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach corrected (correlate the subquery to get the maximum for the group ID of the current row only):

```
CASE WHEN (
  SELECT MAX(item_no)
  FROM my_table m
  WHERE m.group_id = my_table.group_id
) = item_no
  THEN /*logic here*/
```

The alternative with a window function:

```
CASE WHEN MAX(item_no) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) = item_no
  THEN /*logic here*/
```